# underscore.js: key comparision using _.where

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

what if i want to find an object which has same timestamp as my varibale's timestamp in undescore js using _.where.

I have array named data and i want to check that key2.$subkey equals "2014-01-27T16:50:33.035Z" or not.

Following is code for the same.

```
 var data=[{{key1":"key1"},{ "key2" : { "$subkey" : "2014-01-27T16:50:33.035Z"}}},  {{key1":"key1"},{ "key2" : { "$subkey" : "2014-01-27T12:50:33.035Z"}}}];

 var match=_.where(data,{key2.$subkey="2014-01-27T16:50:33.035Z"})
```

how to compare to a key which itself is an object using underscorejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function:

```
var match = _.filter(
    data,
    function (x)
    {
        return x.key2.$subkey == "2014-01-27T16:50:33.035Z"
    })
```

It accepts a predicate function that will be used to determine whether to keep each item or not.

The `where` function is just a specialization of the `filter` function and can be very easily implemented in terms of it.

Comment: is there any option using  where to check x.key2.$subkey=="2014-01-27T16:50:33.035Z"?

Comment: @PriyaBhatt Not that I know of. As I said, `where` is just a special case of `filter`. It's also a really common case. That's likely why the designers of underscore.js decided to provide it, because it's often very convenient.